# Cisco RV180 ipsec vpn to mac os x 10.8.2 default client Configuration

Tags: router, osx-mountain-lion, cisco-vpn-client, ipsec

I would like to configure an IPSec VPN tunnel between my RV180 (server, last firmware) and my Mac OSX 10.8.2 laptop.

I have little knowledge about VPN, and a bit more about network in general. I have generated the RV180 VPN Client base parameters using the RV180 Wizard, with local database users authentication (xauth). My laptop is using the subnet 192.168.2.x (WAN: 85.171.x.x). The RV180 is using the subnet 192.168.1.x (WAN: 85.170.x.x). Both WAN IPs refer to the same ISP. My Mac keeps telling me that it doesn't find the VPN server (the RV180 WAN IP is reachable), I don't know what is going wrong. I don't know where to look or which test to achieve...

Should I modify any generated parameters on RV180 side to match default OSX cisco IPSec VPN client?
Should I open any firewall ports from RV180 firewall?
How should I specify the Group Name in os x vpn client? (does it refer to DH-Group?) the base parameters use Group 2, should I specify "Group2"?